# emacs meta key doesn't respond after setting option key as meta on OSX

Tags: macos, emacs

I recently installed macport emacs and spacemacs with brew. I configured the spacemacs to ivy mode. The problem is after setting the option key as Meta on terminal preference, the output of meta key still comes out as alt on emacs. As I type <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, whether left or right option key, the result comes out as check marks. I restarted laptop after I changed the terminal preference. In fact, I was able to use <kbd>meta</kbd> key in terminal, just not emacs. Any idea?

[the check marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URhfR.png)

Comment: I too am having the same issue. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: @ZachFolwick I didn't find an explicit solution. I think at some moment it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

On [emacs-macport](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/) (`29.1` at least), `(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)` works, i.e. causes `Option` key to work as `Meta` key in GUI mode.